# Does this formula always yield a prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

Somehow $\tau=1.2516475977905$ appears to have the property that
$$
\left\lfloor 2^{2^{{\,}^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\tau}}}}}}\right\rfloor
$$
is always a prime. Here $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the floor function that returns the integral part of $x$.

---

Does this hold? If not, what is wrong with it. If yes, then why.

Comment: Related: (1) and (2) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html).

Comment: This is [Sloane's A051501](http://oeis.org/A051501).